# Laravel Session does not deleted when using flush() or forget()

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to create an `api` which use a `Session` variable. This what I did:

1. Login

```php
return auth('api')->attempt($credentials);
```

2. Call an `api` which save a variable `test` to Session

```php
Session::put('test', $venueId);
```

3. Log out. In `logoutController`, call `Session::flush()` (I tried with `Session::forget('test')` too).

```php
Session::flush();
// Session::forget('test');
auth()->logout();
```

4. Login again.
5. Call `Session:all()` in a randomly `api`. => Variable `test` still there.

I've checked in database, when I use `auth()->logout()` in controller, database create a new session in sessions table which has payload same with payload in step 2. And when I login again, it seems to use 2nd session (which created after logged out in step 3) to get value.

How can I handler this? I want all session to be flushed after user logout

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Sobir sorry for late reply, I've updated code in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out problem. I've used multi authentication, so I have 2 logout controller and I put `Session::flush()` to wrong controller. Put `Session::flush()` into correct controller and it worked.